# How to auto resize text to fit into a rectangle winuser.h

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I have this code here to print centered text:

```
const std::string a= "testddfvdfv dfvdf v";
const CHAR *c = a.c_str();
const RECT b[4] = {x1,y1,x2,y2};
DrawTextA(gui_out._hdc, c, a.size(), const_cast<LPRECT>(b), DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
```

which successfully prints the string a to the center of the rectangle (represented by x1,x2,y1,y2). The only problem is the text is small and doesn't resize based on the rectangle width and height. Is there a way to do this so that the text size auto resizes so that the string fits into the rectangle? Thanks

EDIT: Here is how I am setting up the font. Is there a method of some sort or and algorithm to calculate the necessary font size to fit based on characters?

```
//Two methods for setting font and size
void SetTextSize(int NewFontSize)
{
    gui_out.FontSize = NewFontSize;
}
//---------------------------------------------------
void SetTextFont(string NewFontName)
{
    if (NewFontName == "Arial"
        || NewFontName == "System"
        || NewFontName == "Times New Roman"){
        gui_out.FontName = NewFontName;
        if (NewFontName == "Times New Roman")
            gui_out.FontFamily = FF_ROMAN;
        else
            gui_out.FontFamily = FF_SWISS;
        }
}

void DrawCenteredText(string S)
{
    SetTextColor(gui_out._hdc, RGB(gui_out.RedTextVal, gui_out.GreenTextVal, gui_out.BlueTextVal));
    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(gui_out.FontSize,0,0,0,FW_NORMAL,0,0,0,
            ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            PROOF_QUALITY, gui_out.FontFamily | VARIABLE_PITCH, gui_out.FontName.c_str());
    HFONT hOldFont = HFONT(SelectObject(gui_out._hdc, hFont));
// Below for Visual C++
    POINT P;
    GetCurrentPositionEx(gui_out._hdc, &P);
    SetTextAlign(gui_out._hdc,TA_BASELINE | TA_CENTER | TA_UPDATECP);
    TextOut(gui_out._hdc,P.x,P.x,S.c_str(),S.length());
// Above for Visual C++

    /* This for Borland
    DWORD P = GetCurrentPosition(gui_out._hdc);
    SetTextAlign(gui_out._hdc,TA_BASELINE | TA_CENTER | TA_UPDATECP);
    TextOut(gui_out._hdc,LOWORD(P),HIWORD(P),S.c_str(),S.length());
    */
    SelectObject(gui_out._hdc, hOldFont);
    DeleteObject(hFont);
}
```

Comment: There is no single function that handles this for you. You have to `SelectObject()` an appropriate sized `HFONT` into the `HDC` before printing the text.  You would have to use something like `GetTextExtentPoint32()` in a loop to determine the largest font size that doesn't make the text exceed the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you have example code for how I would do this. I am very new to guis in c++ so any direction helps.

Comment: How are you setting up `gui_out._hdc` before calling `DrawTextA()`? You have to be creating an `HFONT` for it up front.  So you would simply create an `HFONT` in a loop until you find a size that works for your needs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited my original question to include the code about how I am setting up and drawing the text.

Comment: You need to get the current rectangle size in the message loop, and then use [`CreateFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfonta) to set the corresponding font size according to the rectangle size.

Comment: General recommendation: Don't. GUIs are meant to help people navigate data. Font sizes carry semantic value when viewed by a user. Changing the font size just to make text fit into a predefined rectangle is going to make for a pretty poor UI, designed by accident rather than judiciously. Sometimes the code you *don't* write is better code. This is one of those cases.